# Recursive Linq Grouping

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Scenario:
I have database table that stores the hierarchy of another table's many-to-many relationship.  An item can have multiple children and can also have more than one parent.

```
Items    
------ 
ItemID (key)

Hierarchy
---------
MemberID (key)
ParentItemID (fk)
ChildItemID (fk)
```

Sample hierarchy:

```
Level1  Level2  Level3
X       A       A1
                A2
        B       B1
                X1
Y       C
```

I would like to group all of the **child** nodes by *each* **parent** node in the hierarchy.

```
Parent  Child
X       A1
        A2
        B1
        X1
A       A1
        A2
B       B1
        X1
Y       C
```

- Notice how there are no leaf nodes in the Parent column, and how the Child column *only* contains leaf nodes.
- Ideally, I would like the results to be in the form of **IEnumerable<`IGrouping<`Item, Item>>** where the key is a Parent and the group items are all Children.
- Ideally, I would like a solution that the entity provider can translate in to T-SQL, but if that is not possible then I need to keep round trips to a minimum.
- I intend to Sum values that exist in another table joined on the leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are always going to be returning ALL of the items in the table, why not just make a recursive method that gets all children for a parent and then use that on the in-memory Items:

```
partial class Items
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> GetAllChildren()
    {
        //recursively or otherwise get all the children (using the Hierarchy navigation property?)
    }
}
```

then:

```
var items = 
    from item in Items.ToList()
    group new 
    {
        item.itemID,
        item.GetAllChildren()
    } by item.itemID;
```

Sorry for any syntax errors...

Comment: Thank you for your post!  I implemented recursion in a similar fasion.  (+1)  It works will with unit tests but I still need to test it against the database.  If it works well, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the hierarchy is strictly 2 levels you can always union them and let LINQ sort out the SQL (it ends up being a single trip though it needs to be seen how fast it will run on your volume of data):

```
var hlist = from h in Hierarchies
            select new {h.Parent, h.Child};

var slist = from h in Hierarchies
            join h2 in hlist on h.Parent equals h2.Child
            select new {h2.Parent, h.Child};

hlist = hlist.Union(slist);
```

This gives you an flat `IEnumerable<{Item, Item}>` list so if you want to group them you just follow on:

```
var glist = from pc in hlist.AsEnumerable()
            group pc.Child by pc.Parent into g
            select new { Parent = g.Key, Children = g };
```

I used `AsEnumerable()` here as we reached the capability of LINQ SQL provider with attempting to group a Union. If you try it against IQueryable it will run a basic Union for eligable parents then do a round-trip for every parent (which is what you want to avoid). Whether or not its ok for you to use regular LINQ for the grouping is up to you, same volume of data would have to come through the pipe either way.

EDIT: Alternatively you could build a view linking parent to all its children and use that view as a basis for tying Items. In theory this should allow you/L2S to group over it with a single trip.

Comment: I like your answer, however there will be at least 4 levels and the hierarchy will be table driven (user configurable) so there could be any number of levels at run-time.  For this reason I will attempt to use recursion, but I am concerned that the round trips will hurt performance.  I will follow up later.

Comment: How big is your hierarchy? I think you should think a bit ouside the linq box for this one if you want to reduce round trips. Some of the options you might want to explore: 

1. Use sql server hierarchy support and build a view to generate the result you will scoop in one call
2. If the hierarchy table is not too big, just load the whole thing in one scoop and build a hierarchy grouping client side?