# LINQ - Select all in parent-child hierarchy

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I was wondering if there is a neat way do to this, that DOESN'T use any kind of while loop or similar, preferably that would run against Linq to Entities as a single SQL round-trip, and also against Linq To Objects.

I have an entity - `Forum` - that has a parent-child relationship going on. That is, a `Forum` may (or in the case of the top level, may not) have a `ParentForum`, and may have many `ChildForums`. A `Forum` then contains many `Posts`.

What I'm after here is a way to get all the `Posts` from a tree of `Forums` - i.e. the `Forum` in question, and all it's children, grandchildren etc. I don't know in advance how many sub-levels the `Forum` in question may have.

(Note - I know this example isn't necessarily a valuable use case, but the Forum object model one is one that is familiar to most people, and so serves as a generic and accessible premise rather than my actual domain model.)

Comment: you may find this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205777/recursive-linq-grouping useful. Apologies if I interpretted the question incorrectly. if you call the GetChildrenMethod initially, you only do one call to the db

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758162/rendering-a-hierarchy-using-linq

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be if your actual data tables were stored using a left/right tree (example here: http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/ .  Note, that example is in MySQL/PHP, but it's trivial to implement).  Using this, you can find out all forums that fall within a parent's left/right values and given that, you can retrieve all posts who's forum IDs is `IN` those forum IDs.

Comment: Interesting... what happens when you change the structure? Do you then re-build the left/right tree?

Comment: @RichardW1001, yes, there are a set of UPDATES you need to do.  It's generally okay unless you have a seriously massive hierarchy, but in the case of forums and sub-forums I don't see performance being a particular issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you might get a few *proper* answers regarding the Linq queries.  I'm posting this as an advisory when it comes to the SQL side of things.

I had a similar issue with a virtual filesystem in SQL.  I needed to be able to query files in folders recursively - with folders, of course, having a recursive parent-child relationship.  I also needed it to be fast, and I certainly didn't want to be dropping back to client-side processing.

For performance I ended up writing stored procedures and inline functions - unfortunately much too complicated to post here (and I might get the sack for sharing company code!).  The key, however, was to learn how to work with Recursive CTEs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx.  It took me a few days to nail it but the performance is incredible (they are very easy to get wrong though - so pay attention to the query plans).

Comment: Had never heard of recursive CTEs, thanks for sharing and will have a read up on them